# Passport Google strategy - when does the passport.use callback run? The callbackURL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, passport-google-oauth, passport-google-oauth2

I'm using Passport and working on the [Google OAuth 2 strategy](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth2). I'm having trouble understanding the flow.

Here is the code in the [official docs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/google/):

```
var passport = require('passport');
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;

// Use the GoogleStrategy within Passport.
//   Strategies in Passport require a `verify` function, which accept
//   credentials (in this case, an accessToken, refreshToken, and Google
//   profile), and invoke a callback with a user object.
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://www.example.com/auth/google/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
       User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
         return done(err, user);
       });
  }
));
```

And then this for the routes:

```
// GET /auth/google
//   Use passport.authenticate() as route middleware to authenticate the
//   request.  The first step in Google authentication will involve
//   redirecting the user to google.com.  After authorization, Google
//   will redirect the user back to this application at /auth/google/callback
app.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'] }));

// GET /auth/google/callback
//   Use passport.authenticate() as route middleware to authenticate the
//   request.  If authentication fails, the user will be redirected back to the
//   login page.  Otherwise, the primary route function function will be called,
//   which, in this example, will redirect the user to the home page.
app.get('/auth/google/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

Here's my understanding of the flow. User clicks a button to log in with google on the browser. Request is sent to `/auth/google`. Which calls `passport.authenticate`. From there, Google handles some stuff and once the user gives us permission to access their Google account, well, that's the part I'm not understanding.

What's the next step? It seems like Google will send a response to the `callbackURL` we provide. But in that case, when does the callback to `passport.use` run? That callback is accepting `accessToken`, `refreshToken`,  and `profile`, so it seems like it is the one receiving the response from Google, not the `callbackURL`.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer is sufficient, otherwise, I can do my best to add more detail.

Answer (score 0):

In your application, when a user gives you permission to authenticate **their** account via Google for the first time, two possible 'flows' to consider:

- user already has an existing account in **your** system and would like to link that account to her Google identity.
- user is creating a new account in your system and you provide her with an option to create a new account using her Google identity

The end result if the user opts to authenticate using Google is a record in your database containing additional information provided from Google's auth service response. The data looks something similar to [this page in passport docs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/profile/).

The `passport.use(...)` call with the first argument of an object with your tokens is what passport uses to access Google's system (standard OAUTH2 credentials). The second argument is the callback function that interacts with your system's data layer, ex: `User.findOrCreate(data)`.

On future visits to your application, a user can take advantage of the fact that their account is 'connected' with their Google identity and have a simple sign-in experience.

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks for the response. I'm still not understanding when exactly that second argument to `passport.use(...)` gets executed, and when the `callbackURL` gets hit.